# Using a ledger to call a smart contract on NEAR in CLI version 4+

Tags: nearprotocol

It looks like the `useLedgerKey` flag has been deprecated in `near-cli` version 4+ but it's not clear what the replacement syntax is.

For example, how would I run the equivalent of this in the new cli:

`near call some_contract.near some_method '{"key":"value"}' --accountId=my_account.near --useLedgerKey="44'/397'/0'/0'/8'"`

Note that I'm using an arbitrary Ledger HD Path, not the default `44'/397'/0'/0'/1'`

References:

- [NEAR Cli v3.5 docs](https://github.com/near/near-cli/tree/3.5.0?tab=readme-ov-file#near-generate-key) contain the `useLedgerKey` option

Answer (score 0):

The recommended path forward is to use the new [near.cli.rs](https://near.cli.rs), which has much more features. Just install it using the instructions in the readme and run `near` command to trigger interactive mode or paste your command as is to see how it will suggest to transform it.

Pro tip: If you want to use both old and new CLIs side-by-side, use `npx`. Here is the command to run the new CLI without installing it as a replacement for `near` command:

```
npx near-cli-rs
```

```
npx near-cli-rs contract \
  call-function as-transaction some_contract.near some_method \
  json-args '{"key":"value"}' \
  prepaid-gas '30 TeraGas' \
  attached-deposit '0 NEAR' \
  sign-as my_account.near
```